# how to store worker-local variables in dask/distributed

Tags: python, distributed, dask

Using dask 0.15.0, distributed 1.17.1.

I want to memoize some things per worker, like a client to access google cloud storage, because instantiating it is expensive. I'd rather store this in some kind of worker attribute. What is the canonical way to do this? Or are globals the way to go?

Answer (score 8):

#### On the worker

You can get access to the local worker with the [get_worker](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.get_worker) function.  A slightly cleaner thing than globals would be to attach state to the worker:

```
from dask.distributed import get_worker

def my_function(...):
    worker = get_worker()
    worker.my_personal_state = ...

future = client.submit(my_function, ...)
```

We should probably add a generic namespace variable on workers to serve as a general place for information like this, but haven't yet.

#### As Globals

That being said though, for things like connections to external services globals aren't entirely evil.  Many systems like Tornado use global singletons.

#### If you care about thread safety

Note that workers are often multi-threaded.  If your connection object isn't threadsafe then you may need to cache a different object per-thread.  For this I recommend using a `threading.local` object.  Dask uses one at

```
from distributed.worker import thread_state
```

Answer (score 1):

**Dask Actors**

For simpler use cases, other solutions may be preferable; however, its worth considering Actors.  Actors are currently an experimental feature in Dask which enables stateful computations.

[Dask Actors](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/actors.html?highlight=worker%20state)

Comment: Did not notice yet - Thanks! Do you know if you could also submit data to the `Actors` on a high speed? Like using the Actor as a data holder for bigger `DataFrames` or `np.array`?